# How to impose soft_heap method to limit database to 5GB in sqlite

Tags: c, sqlite, limit

How can i limit my database to 5GB using the soft_heap_limit method? If it overflows 5GB i want to delete the oldest record based on timestamp.

How do i trigger the soft_heap_limit method/PRAGMA in sqlite using c lang. I am not using any ID though. Since the data is variable i won't know the size of count/row.

Comment: What have you tried? Something like this?
`sqlite3_int64 5gb = 5 * (1 <<30);`
`sqlite3_int64 sqlite3_soft_heap_limit64(5gb);`

It looks like with this function sqlite controls which records get removed from cache though.

Comment: So i defined a SOFT_HEAP_LIMIT to 5kb and then called sqlite3_soft_heap_limit64(SOFT_HEAP_LIMIT) method while creating the table.

Code Snippet :

static const sqlite3_int64 SOFT_HEAP_LIMIT = 5 * 1024 * 1024;

int rc = sqlite3_soft_heap_limit64(SOFT_HEAP_LIMIT);
 if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);}
  
I inserted records more than 5kb, but i still do not get SQLITE_FULL error 
Please let me know what can i do to set the limit and trigger an error when it exceeds that limit?

Comment: I get a syntax error when running: `sqlite3_int64 2gb = 2 * (1 <<30); sqlite3_int64 sqlite3_soft_heap_limit64(2gb);`